# Performance extracting SQL results to CSV many rows vs many columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have a query that I need to run that I can with a lot of effort transpose in the database so that it is 'tidy' e.g., not in the typical sql-group-by format.   Or I can just export as in the standard SQL group by statement resulting in a table that is significantly longer (more rows) with just a couple of columns.

Is there any sort of general guidance when exporting to CSV out of the DB - is it more effecient to  say a   200,000 x 900 table or a   180,000,000 x 3  table ?( = 200,000 * 900).

To make this more real - say I want to do this query where there are hundreds of thousands of companies and ~200 countries in the world.  The normal SQL-group by would be quiet a long table.  If I transpose so that each country is a column and the company is a row it gets quiet wide.

This is postgresql if the matters.  Looking for some DB expert's opinion on this.

```
select company, country, sum(spend)
from country_table
group by company, country
```

Comment: I think the two dimensions you gave are not very relevant, because the final CSV file would be nearly the same size.  The bigger question is what format do _you_ need for your work/research?

Comment: I can transpose without too much trouble out of the DB.  The main question is around the SQL run time to export...so you are saying that it shouldn't matter ( as long as rows x columns =   columns x rows or the same number ?)

Comment: I think the time to export should correlate strongly with the amount of data you are writing to disk.  The writing to disk part is probably the bottleneck.  So choose a format that works for your problem and go with it.

Comment: The format/structure of the export file should be determined by the way you want to _use_ that file later on. The overall size of the file will not change just because you turn many rows into many columns.